How to fix blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) in ruby on rails app(Render)?


**
I'm using hotwired/stimulus and importmap_tags for JavaScript in my Ruby on Rails app. In development, everything works fine, but after deploying to Render, my sales view and the product with variants form (which generates variants through scripts) are not functioning.
**
Here’s my folder structure for the JavaScript files:

app/
javascript/
application.js
controllers/
new_product_controller.js
edit_product_controller.js
sales_controller.js
catalog_controller.js
index.js
variant_controller.js
and more...

Additionally, I have this in my app/bin/render-build.js:
set -o errexit
bundle install
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
bundle exec rails assets:clean
# Uncomment the following line if using a Free instance:
bundle exec rails db:migrate

And in my render.yaml, the config looks like this:
databases:
  - name: inventory_management_demo
    databaseName: inventory_management_demo
    user: inventory_management_demo_user
    plan: free
    region: singapore
    ipAllowList:
      - source: 0.0.0.0/0
        description: everywhere
    postgresMajorVersion: "16"

services:
  - type: web
    name: mysite
    runtime: ruby
    plan: free
    buildCommand: "./bin/render-build.sh"
    startCommand: "bundle exec rails server"
    envVars:
      - key: DATABASE_URL
        fromDatabase:
          name: inventory_management_demo
          property: connectionString
      - key: RAILS_MASTER_KEY
        sync: false
      - key: WEB_CONCURRENCY
        value: 2

Everything works as expected in development, but after deploying to Render, I'm getting errors in the console and can't figure out how to fix them. Any help would be appreciated,

with the way rails does importmaps by default you can't use relative imports for javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/78626867/207090

@Alex I have one small doubt, do i need to add absolute path for all the imports in my index.js file (javascript>controllers>index.js ) and currently in my importmap.rb file i have this code :
`
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
and in my application.html.erb i have this line in the head tag : 
<%= javascript_importmap_tags 'application' %>
`

yes, you need to change all your imports. but you don't really need to do anything with controllers/index.js, keep it as generated by default https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/blob/main/lib/install/app/javascript/controllers/index_for_importmap.js
